# Prove or disprove $\sigma ($ singletons $ \in ℝ) = B(ℝ) $

Tags: measure-theory

${ E  }_{ 1 }:=\{ \left( -\infty ,x \right) :x\in \Re \}$

${ E  }_{ 2 }:=\{ \left\{ x \right\} :x\in \Re \}$

Prove $\sigma \left( { E  }_{ 1 } \right) =\sigma \left( { E  }_{ 2 } \right) $

**My Attempt:**

Note: I know 
${ E  }_{ 1 }$  generates the Borel field

(i.e.) $\sigma \left( { E  }_{ 1 } \right)=B(ℝ)$

I know the statement is wrong as  $\sigma \left( { E  }_{ 2 } \right) \varsubsetneqq \sigma \left( { E  }_{ 1 } \right)$

Hence I try to do it by contradiction. Assume $\sigma \left( { E  }_{ 1 } \right) \subseteq \sigma \left( { E  }_{ 2 } \right)$

Let $F \in σ(E_{1})$ be a non-empty set

As $F \in E_{1} \Rightarrow F \in σ(E_{1})$

When $F \in E_{1}$, $F = (-\infty, x)$ for some $x \in ℝ$

I want to prove that for some $x \in ℝ$, $F = (-\infty, x) \notin E_{2}$, which means $F = (-\infty, x) \notin σ(E_{2})$.
It is kind of obvious to me as  $-∞ \notin ℝ$, and $x \in ℝ$ implies that $(-\infty, x)$ cannot be generated by a countable union of singletons.

Hence $\sigma \left( { E  }_{ 1 } \right) \subseteq \sigma \left( { E  }_{ 2 } \right)$ must be wrong.

But I'm not sure if this statement is strong enough or even correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No. Consider the subsets of the real line that are countable or co-countable (complements countable). This is a $\sigma$-algebra.  It contains all singletons.  It is not the Borel sets.

Comment: It's the "buckshot" $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Do u mean that once the sigma-algebra contains all singletons, it will not be the Borel Set? Is it trival? Or there is some sort of proof required for that step?

Comment: It will not be.  Look at what I said.

Comment: I'm very sorry.....I'm not sure what do you mean by "buckshot" $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Either "buckshot" (a countable subset) is present or it is absent.

Comment: I still can't get it. Would you mind explaining again? I understand that the subset of the real line that are countable or co-countable is a sigma-algebra. It contains all singletons because singletons itself is countable. Since this sigma algebra is a set that countable subset is present or absent, it will not be the Borel set?

Comment: The Borel sets contain all intervals. This $sigma$-algebra contains no interval, save for the entire line.